# Probability that partition problem has a solution for sets of random integers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization

The [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) wikipedia page has a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Partition_problem) devoted to the problem of finding the minimum $N$ such that the probability $p_N$ that $N$ numbers randomly chosen with [replacement](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallPicking.html) from $\{1,2,...,1000000\}$ can be [partitioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) into two [subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) whose [sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) differ by at most $1$ satisfies $p_N>\frac{1}{2}$. The answer given is $N=23$, and the explanation is that there are $2^{N-1}$ partitions and the [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) of the sum of the weights is [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with width approximately $1000000\sqrt{N}$. It is then claimed that the critical value of $N$ is that for which $1000000\sqrt{N}\approx2^{N-1}$ which gives $N=23$ as the closest value.

I do not follow this argument; in particular, I cannot see why the width approximation of $1000000\sqrt{N}$ is used or why $p_N$ will be greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ when the number of partitions is larger than the width. The page references [this paper](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/fabio-lucio.toninelli/BCP.pdf), which investigates the behaviour of the problem as $N\rightarrow\infty$ and the number of weights to choose from is increased proportional to $N$. Looking through the paper, I did not find any result which seemed to answer our problem, as most results were for [asymptotically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) large $N$, and I couldn't find anything which seemed to justify wikipedia's working.

Thus I would like the answer to the following problem: let $N$ weights be chosen with integer values randomly drawn from $\{1,2,...,M\}$ (I'd be happy to see results with or without replacement) and let $p(N,M)$ be the probability of existence of an equal-weight (with or without allowance for a discrepancy of 1 unit) two-subset partition of the weights. (Without allowance for discrepancy, $p(N,M)$ is the probability that the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) has a solution). Then what is $N_{min}(M)=\min{\left\{N\;|\;p(N,M)>\frac{1}{2}\right\}}$?

I have attempted in the past to solve this by trying to find an exact expression for $p(N,M)$, by looking for expressions for the number of possible partitions with equal weights using [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) but I have never had success, and I don't know if this is an appropriate way to go about it. I have searched for any similar question on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=partition+problem+weight) also but all of the results seem to be more concerned with [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) and other [computational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation) considerations relating to the partition problem.

My question is: can anyone find a way of calculating $N_{min}(M)$ or even $p(N,M)$ or present a good approximation, or possibly elucidate wikipedia's calculation?

Comment: Have you read the paper cited in that wikipedia section? http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/fabio-lucio.toninelli/BCP.pdf

Comment: @MatthewConroy Yes, that's the paper I refer to in the 2nd paragraph. I wasn't able to find a relevant result in it though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that.  Yes, I agree, that paper doesn't seem to directly address what is given in the WP section.  (At the very least, it doesn't mention "23".) That section needs better/more citations.